# list_resources() from AzureRMR fails for some subscriptions with "Invalid object names" error

Tags: r, azure

I'm trying to list all the resources in a subscription using `AzureRMR` package.
Unfortunately, it fails with the following error.

```r
library(AzureRMR)

az <- get_azure_login()
#> Loading Azure Resource Manager login for default tenant
az$
  get_subscription('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000')$
  list_resources()
#> Error in validate_object_names(names(parms), required_names, optional_names): Invalid object names
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I tried it for another subscription and it works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reference, this is because some resource types (VMs and disks in particular, but possibly also others) have fields that aren't in the base definition found in the Resource Manager documentation. The latest version of AzureRMR (2.3.3 as of June 2020) fixes this issue.

Comment: Thanks again for fixing it, @Hong.